Form to Excel, Power Automate: Only replace excel rows if not duplicates
I have a Microsoft form that is using a flow from power automate to populate an excel spreadsheet.
There are multiple users of the form and have noticed lately that some users are entering data twice and we are finding duplicates in our data. This is a live data source and needs to be as accurate as possible at all times.
Is there a way to only add a row to the spreadsheet through power automate if the primary key (ID) is not a duplicate?
Thanks!
remove duplicates in excel

Trigger should be When a new response is submitted. Then Get response details to get the Form ID. Then Excel Get a row to check if there is a matching row already.
If there is a matching row - what do you want to do? I've used Update a row, but you can do something else like delete, create an email to notify someone, etc.
Then add the Add a row activity to the end of the flow. To get the branching activity, select the Add a row activity, go to Settings, Run After, Select Actions, and set it to run after Get a row Has failed.

